# How could I build a Login form for my program with java?

Tags: java, authentication

I'm going to build a messenger and for the first step I have to build the login and sign-up features. How should I do this? I'm coding with java

Comment: What software stack are you using? Client side: Swing? Server side: Java EE?

Comment: @Puce yes probably, I use them unless I get recommendations for using something else

Comment: @spork What other information should I have provided? That was all I know from what I want to do. The problem is a little ambiguous to myself to, I wanted to get a clue to know where should I start, I've never done any authorization project. I've did some research and come up with JAAS which at the first look I didnt know would that be enough for what I'm going to do or not, so I asked here for just some keywords to know about all these stuff.

Comment: @Kamran The account creation and log in mechanisms are different for the many instant messaging services that already exist. If you're trying to build a completely new protocol, your question is so broad as to be difficult to address. The title of your question is "How could I build a Login form for my program with java?", which implies you have a question about using client-side Java APIs, but your question's details are about protocols. You might consider breaking your problem into smaller pieces and addressing individual questions.

Comment: @spork yes you are right, I think It was better to do some more research about it at first, however I got my clues from the answers and I started coding it. I think I will ask more specific questions later about some details of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use WindowBuilder Pro and Eclipse IDE to initially make the form. Grab Eclipse IDE, then install like so: http://code.google.com/javadevtools/download-wbpro.html, http://code.google.com/javadevtools/wbpro/installation/index.html. Then use RMI to do the authentication from the form.

[image: WindowBuilder Pro]

Comment: What's RMI? How would be the authentication?

Comment: RMI is Remote Method Invocation (Google it, but be aware that from Java 1.5 stub generation is no longer required). When the client connects, you create an object for them, with a proxy on the client side (used to alter state of the object on the Java side). You can then use the proxy to communicate with that, calling authentication methods.

Answer (score 1):

Java on the web?

Use a HTML form.

Java on the desktop?

Use can use Swing. Create a JFrame with a JPanel containing JTextField(s), JTextArea(s) and JButton(s).

Comment: It's on desktop, my question is about the APIs I should use for getting the username and passwords and sending them to servers and How to process these credentials and responding. and How to use these APIs

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at JAAS, the Java Authentication and Authorization Service.